# Rest Sharp .NET core vs Framework

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I'm not very familiar with APIs or the nuances of .NET

I've written an application that functions as a test in a .NET core 3.0 console application. However, when I attempt to use the same code in my larger application (.NET framework 4.7.2) it does not work correctly. Seems like an authentication problem but I get no errors in build or run.

Below is the code if that helps.

```cs
static string Login()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    
    var client = new RestClient("https://192.168.110.160/apis/v2/login");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    client.UserAgent = "python-requests/2.10.0";

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Host", "192.168.110.160");
    request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "47");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    request.AddHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=gl5wrkatrptuv8tsbbsej619a8");
    request.AddParameter("text/plain", "{\"username\": \"user1234\", \"password\": \"passwor\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: Your code never checks if the response was successful. Try checking `StatusCode`, `StatusDescription`, `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorException`. BTW .NET Core 3.0 was a short-term release that's already out of support. The Long-Term-Support (3 years) version is .NET Core 3.1

Comment: "it does not work correctly" does not say much, can you please expand on that?

Comment: If you don't check the response status, how can you say it's not successful?